# mix microphone with mp3 file and output that to specific device

Tags: c#, naudio

I'd like to be able to mix the microphone output with a mp3-File, and output that to a specific device.

I got playing the mp3-File to a specific device working:

```
Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader("C:\\Users\\Victor\\Music\\Musik\\Attack.mp3");
var waveOut = new WaveOut();// or WaveOutEvent()
waveOut.DeviceNumber = deviceId; //deviceId, like 0 or 1
waveOut.Init(reader);
waveOut.Play();
```

So would I would like to be able to do is basically send the microphone output always to specific output and overlay that output to that specific device with the sound of a mp3-file when for example a button is pressed.
Now is what I'm trying to do possible with naudio and if so how would I go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to take a look at the `MixingWaveProvider32` that allows mixing multiple channels into one output. And Then mix a `WaveIn.StartRecording()` together with your Mp3FileReader's stream. I hope this put you in the right direction!

Comment: Thanks for your comment- unforunately I'm not sure how to get an object suitable for MixingWaveProvider32 constructor which needs an object with a Type implementing IEnumerable<IWaveProvider>.How would I get that out of the mp3filereader and the microphone Input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic strategy is to put the audio rececived from the microphone into a `BufferedWaveProvider`. Then turn that into an `ISampleProvider` with the `ToSampleProvider` extension method. Now you can pass that into a `MixingSampleProvider`. Then play from the `MixingSampleProvider`. Now at any time you can mix in other audio by adding an input into the `MixingSampleProvider`